# issues using waitpid() with large number of child process

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I have a c program to create a TCP socket and keep waiting for a connection in an infinite loop. Each time a client connected to the program, I would spawn a new child process to handle the client request. My program could only exit with signal interrupt (e.g.  `ctrl+c`).

I don't want the parent process hanging there and wait for a child and I hope they could work simultaneously. **What the parent process should do after forking is to check if any children have finished, and if so, clean them up**.

currently my approach is(**no error checking at here to save space, there are a lot of error checking in my real code**):

```
if (fork()==0){
    /* Child process. */
}
else{
    close(client);    /* <- Cut down the connection from parent with the client. */
    waitpid(0, &status_exit, WNOHANG|WUNTRACED);
    child_spawn++;    /* One parent int variable to count total number of child process. */
}
```

But this rise another issue, since the parent will always hang and waiting for a connection, there **could always be one or two previous finished child process that cannot be cleaned up until the parent could fork another and clean them up**.

Even though my program could clean every zombie once it receives a signal interrupt before exit, but I want it to clean up every finished child by itself.

Please help me with this, thanks. If I have anything that's not clarified, please leave a comment so I could explain.

Comment: Since your are using `WNOHANG` you can loop on `waitpid` while its return value is not 0 (no more dead child) and not -1 (error). Looping on `wait` actually is the right method to use when managing multiple processes.

Comment: This is an instance of the general problem of how to wait for _either_ an I/O event or the termination of a child process, whichever comes first; Unix has never made this easy or neat.  The cleanest way I know of to handle it is with the Linux-specific `signalfd` interface. A less tidy but more portable way uses a thread dedicated to calling `waitpid`. And an even uglier method, which does at least avoid both threads and OS-specific extensions to POSIX, is with `pselect` and a `SIGCHLD` handler.  Are any of these options acceptable to you?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Thanks this is a good idea. But since the parent would be stuck waiting for connections, any child processes finished at this point would become zombies and cannot be cleaned up until the parent proceed.

Comment: @zwol I'm currently using `waitpid(0, &status_exit, WNOHANG|WUNTRACED);` after the parent spawns a child process to check if there are any uncleaned finished process.

Comment: @Rrobinvip You can't avoid zombies... But, you can use `SIGCHLD` to catch deaths and loop over `waitpid` in the catching function.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Thanks I would do some search on that

Comment: @Rrobinvip Thanks, but that isn't an answer to the question I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing you can do is for the parent to wait in a loop of `accept(2)` calls, accepting the incoming connections of the clients and forking children to attend the connections.  Register a signal handler for the `SIGCHLD` signal that simply makes a `wait(2)` call and queues the exit code on some queue for the parent process to handle when it has the time to do so.  For example, the parent can accept a connection, fork a child and process all the exit codes enqueued by the interrupt handlers to clean the children data.  After that, it comes back to `accept(2)` to welcome the new client.